# Securely sharing access across subnets with point to multipoint wireless

Tags: wireless, vlan, point-to-point

I might be over thinking things, but I'm lost.  I'm trying to modernize our farm.  Cable broadband comes into the farmhouse.  Spread throughout our multi-acre property, we have a total of 7 buildings (including farmhouse).  I want internet shared to all 7.  I want isolation (at least with some) because there are seasonal workers and/or guests and I don't want different buildings being able to see files in other buildings.  However, I think I want one server available to all buildings.  In fact, it wouldn't be a bad idea to be able to, for example, put an IP camera out at an outbuilding and have it accessible at the house.  So I want security/isolation, but with the ability to modify that as desired (if possible).

The distances are too far for CAT, and I can't really trench anyway without incurring unacceptable costs.  So the building-to-building connections have to be wireless.

I've done a reasonable amount of Googling over the past few days and I think I've figured out the hardware for the wireless:  point to multipoint.  One high powered Omni AP on the roof of the house with high powered directional bridges on each building with a wifi router in each to serve their own subnets.

I'm not yet talking about configuration at all.  I'm currently just trying to figure out the hardware.

Besides the wireless AP/bridges I described above... I think I need a vlan enabled switch and a router on a stick.  *What hardware do I require, end-to-end, to have communication between clients of a building and between clients and server in other buildings while blocking communication client-of-one-building with client-of-another?*

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networing and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask about those on [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concepts:

VLAN: a logical separation of networked devices (Different IP address ranges as well) on the same switch or multiple switches such that users of one VLAN can not communicate with the users of other VLANs unless there is a router (a layer 3 device) that routes the traffic between them.

A trunk link: a network link that carries more than one VLAN. The traffic of each VLAN is marked so the other end knows what traffic goes in which VLAN. If the other end is a device that only needs one VLAN, it will take the relevant traffic and ignore the traffic.

Router on a stick: It is a layer 3 device capable of routing traffic between different VLANs but it has only one physical link. The traffic comes to the router in a trunk on the link and gets routed from one VLAN to other on the same link.

UTM: Unified Threat Management box that provides firewall, routing, authentication, anti-malware, web filtering, guest user authentication and more.

Your basic requirements are:

- Internet access in 7 buildings where these buildings are more than 120 meters from each other. You have a main building where internet is available. (UTP cables are not an option for buildings connectivity)
- You want a guest access in addition to normal user access in those buildings for temporary users.
- You want security cameras installed and their traffic to be isolated from users for security reasons.
- You want users of each building to be separated from users of other buildings such that you can control who sees what.
- You need a central server available to users of your choice.
- I am assuming that your users in each building will be both wired and wireless so they can utilize internet on their mobile phones as well.

In terms of the hardware, you will need the following:

- A switch in each building. This switch can be layer 2 switch (only VLANs with no local routing) or it could be a layer three capable switch that will do routing as well. The selection criteria depends on what type of setup you are looking for. In case of layer 2 switch, all traffic will always be sent over the wireless links to the gateway in the main building if the traffic is junk causing unnecessary traffic on your wireless links eating up your valuable bandwidth unless you have high capacity wireless links. Layer 3 switch on the other hand can be setup to filter some traffic locally and block any unnecessary traffic over the wireless links. Each VLAN will have it's own subnet and the gateway of each VLAN will have to be on the local switch in case of layer 3 switches in each site or on the central router/firewall in case you installed layer 2 switches in site.
- For the wireless setup, you will need one or two Omni directional Antenna Access Points depending on the wireless capacity of the APs, location of the buildings to be connected and possible obstacles in the line of sight between the buildings. You should get a professional do a survey for you before installing the wireless network. The APs that will connect more than one building or the buildings where you will have more than one VLAN must support multi VLAN trunking so that you could have each site in one  or more VLANs instead of one flat VLAN for all sites.
- You will need a layer 3 device with firewall capabilities in the main site that will give you control on which traffic/user is allowed to go where. The [SOPHOS](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-utm-home-edition.aspx) free box is a good choice if your number of users are less than 50. Else you will have to buy another one of your choice that gives you the desired functionality. I would suggest that you go for a UTM to make it easier on your self.
- You will need a server for whatever the reason you want it for as per your needs and put it on the switch of main building. It is a good idea that you put it on a separate VLAN (with different IP range) to have more control on what users are allowed to access your server from different VLANs.
- You will need indoor access points for each building either with a controller or without. The controller will help in managing the APs if you have many and require a lot of changes on the wireless network frequently. I don’t think that it is the case in your case and you can do without a controller. Just keep wireless users on different VLANs from the wired users. Also, you can have different wireless VLAN for temporary guest access.
- You will need to do internal cabling and have the patch panels and cabinets as your budget allows.

This is the basic design of your requirements.

Comment: Considor writing a comment if you think an answer is not helpful.

Comment: just so you know, it certainly wasn't me that gave you -1.  Although, it didn't really address my question.  The only parts you mentioned were the parts I had listed (thanks for the confirmation though).  I'm not really understanding VLAN requirements I guess, and my Googling has come up with more questions than answers. For example, I read about "router on a stick" in several places, but they don't go into detail.  I have to ASSUME (which is always dangerous) that it needs to be a vlan capable router, but nothing states that explicitly.  Does any cheap-o router work because the switchis vlan?

Comment: I will edit my answer to make it more clear. In your question, you asked about the hardware and that is what I clarified. I will see if it is possible to draw a diagram for you.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, I don't have the "reputation" to +1 your answer.  It is appreciated though.

Comment: That is fine. I was not looking for the +1. Just wanted to help. :)